# origami folding problem - nose

Tags: geometry, origami

There is a square sheet of paper with points $A (0:0:0), B (0:1:0), C (1:1:0)$, and $D (1:0:0)$. The paper is folded along the diagonal, aligning point B with point $D$ (the sheet is divided into two polygons, ABC and ADC). Then, the sheet is folded inward at point C (creating a nose) between the polygons at position $C (1.2:0.5:0)$. Points $A\times C \implies O$, $B\times C \implies  E$, and $D\times C \implies F$ are added. This results in the larger polygons $AOEB$ and $AOFD$, and the smaller polygons $OEC$ and $OFC$. It is necessary to determine the position of point $C$ when we raise the $AOEB$ polygon by $30^\circ$ (angle of opening) from the tabletop around the edge $AO$, while symmetrically lowering the AOFD polygon by $30^\circ$ with respect to the tabletop around the edge $AO$. Points $A, O$, and $C$ remain in the tabletop plane. A general formula is needed as the position of point $C$ during the folding of the nose and the angle of opening may vary.

[Unfolded sheet picture](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cwkzevme):
[image]

[Folded sheet picture](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ys76pej6):
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what $O$ is? Also, what is "AxC"?

Comment: Take a real square sheet of paper and mark the corners A, B, C, D. The edge AC is formed by folding the sheet along the diagonal, and when we fold point C inward, the edge AC is divided into two parts, and a new point AxC appears, which I called O (the edges CB new point CxB => E and CD new point CxD => F are also divided). Visually, this creates a triangular shape with an inward-pointing "nose".

Comment: * Visually, when viewed from above, it forms a triangle with the top corner truncated, and a small protruding "nose" from the inside.

Comment: Unfolded sheet - https://www.geogebra.org/m/cwkzevme
Folded sheet - https://www.geogebra.org/m/ys76pej6

Comment: You should think of it as doing the pocket fold after the wings are set to 30 degree angles to the table.  Point C will be mirrored across the plane containing EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take point $C=(1,1)$ to point $P=(a,b)$
the sheet of paper must be folded along the
perpendicular bisector $FO$ of segment $PC$
(see figure below; as I'm working in the $(x,y)$ plane
it's convenient to drop $z$ coordinates).
A straightforward computation gives the equation of line $FO$:
$$
y-{1+b\over2}=-{a-1\over b-1}\left(x-{1+a\over2}\right).
$$
Substituting $y=x$ into that equation we can find the coordinates of $O$:
$$
x_O=y_O={a^2+b^2-2\over2(a+b-2)}.
$$
And substituting $x=1$ we can find the coordinates of $F$:
$$
x_F=1,\quad y_F={a^2+b^2-2a\over2(b-1)}.
$$

When quadrilateral $AOFD$ rotates about line $AC$,
point $F$ describes a circle with centre $R$
(the projection of $F$ on line $AC$).
If $F'$ is the rotated image of $F$ and $Q$ its projection on
$(x,y)$ plane, then $RQ=RF\cos\alpha$,
where $\alpha$ is the rotation angle.
The coordinates of $Q$ are $(1-\delta,y_F+\delta)$, where:
$$
\delta={FQ\over\sqrt2}={RF(1-\cos\alpha)\over\sqrt2}
={CF(1-\cos\alpha)\over2}=
{2b+2a-a^2-b^2-2\over4(b-1)}(1-\cos\alpha).
$$
As a result of the rotation, point $P$ moves to $C'$,
staying on the $(x,y)$ plane.
Note that $OC'=OP=OC$ and $F'C'=FP=FC=F'C$.
The first equality implies that $C'$ lies on the circle
through $C$ of centre $O$.
The second equality implies that $C'$ lies on the circle
through $C$ of centre $Q$.

As the coordinates of $O$, $C$, $Q$ are known,
we can write down the equations of those two circles
and find the coordinates of $C'$.

I did the task with some help from Mathematica and got:

$$
x_{C'}=\frac{(a+b-2) (a^2+b^2-a-b) \cos ^2(\alpha )
+(a^2+b^2-2a-2b+2) (a-b) \cos (\alpha)+(a-b)^2}
{(a+b-2)^2 \cos ^2(\alpha )+(a-b)^2}
\\
\ \\
y_{C'}=\frac{(a+b-2) (a^2+b^2-a-b) \cos ^2(\alpha )
-(a^2+b^2-2a-2b+2) (a-b) \cos (\alpha)+(a-b)^2}
{(a+b-2)^2 \cos ^2(\alpha )+(a-b)^2}
$$

[image]

EDIT.

Here's an animated figure, made with GeoGebra, showing the sheet of paper while folding and unfolding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to test this solution on my 3D model within 24 hours and will report the results here.

Comment: can you clarify the statement that "The second equality implies that ′
  lies on the circle through  of center " maybe I'm missing something, but the projections FC, F′ onto the plane (x,y) are not equal and depend on the angle, but as far as I understand everything is considered in this plane, and why do we choose point C and not P for example for this statement?

Comment: When point $F$ is lifted to $F'$, point $P$ is carried to $C'$. Distances $FP$ and $F'C'$ must be the same, but also $FP=FC=F'C$ (because $C$ is on the rotation axis), hence $F'C'=F'C$. As $Q$ is the projection of $F'$ on the $(x,y)$ plane, this also entails $QC=QC'$.

Comment: Distances  and ′′ must be the same in volume, in projection on plane its not true

Comment: @NikitaPrasolov Yes, of course: $F'$ is NOT on the $(x,y)$ plane and is not represented in the diagram.

Comment: Thank you very match. Animation looks amazing and right. Still not understand what rule or logic you use for F'C = FC :)